# This code needs to execute without adding objects in local object repository

Tags: automation, qtp

```
SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files\MozillaFirefox\firefox.exe","https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2"
Browser ("text=Google - Mozilla Firefox").Page("text=Google - Mozilla Firefox").WebEdit("text=Google - Mozilla Firefox").Set "Ram"
Browser ("text=Google - Mozilla Firefox").Page("text=Google - Mozilla Firefox").WebButton("text=Google - Mozilla Firefox").Click
```

I am using Quick test professional and I want to open google in mozilla and want to search "Ram".when i am executing this code its showing Object not found in object repository but this is descriptive programming,no need to add object in local object repository.

Comment: You're getting that particular error because you didn't use := to separate your name/value pairs of descriptive programming, so it's interpreting the string as an OR object name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the object spy in qtp to identify correct object properties. The Browser object here does not have the text property, instead you should have used title as the identifying property.

Also the url you've given seems to be pointing to Gmail instead of Google search.

Here's an example for IE, hope that helps

```
SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe", "www.google.com"
Browser("title:=Google").Page("title:=Google").WebEdit("name:=q").Set ("Ram")
Browser("title:=Google").Page("title:=Google").WebEdit("name:=q").Submit
```

Comment: How to use object spy for winobject ?when i am trying to identify the google page by object spy its showing same property for all objects.If it is possible please help me with the screen shot.

     Browser("title:=Google").Page("title:=Google").WebEdit("name:=q").Set ("Ram")
Browser("title:=Google").Page("title:=Google").WebEdit("name:=q").Submit

Comment: These both lines are not executing,this error is displaying:- 

Cannot find the "[ WebEdit ]" object's parent "[ Browser ]" (class Browser). Verify that parent properties match an object currently displayed in your application.
Line (51): "Browser("title:=Google").Page("title:=Google").WebEdit("name:=q").Set ("Ram")". 

Tip: If the objects in your application have changed, the Maintenance Run Mode can 
help you identify and update your steps and/or the objects in your repository.

Comment: Do you have the web add-in selected? The example above is a working example.

Comment: Yes I have selected all three add-in.

Comment: Please try with only web add-in selected. The above snippet works for me with only the web add-in selected.

Comment: yesterday only I have tried,only google page is opening and after that process stopped .